# Verilog codes of Riscv-Boom

Tags: riscv

could someone please help me how to generate Verilog codes of Riscv-Boom?
I did everything in this repository, but still I do not know how to generate Verilog codes of Riscv-Boom.
https://github.com/ucb-bar/riscv-boom

Comment: What is your exact problem? Please read and follow this guide when you ask question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows up in generated-src/*.v when you follow the README.